# Ember QUnit: moduleForHelper with ember metal-views

Tags: ember.js, ember-qunit

For our ember app we want to test the handlebars helpers. Currently we use the moduleForHelper from [this never merged ember-qunit PR](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit/pull/11). With ember 1.8 beta-1 (which includes the metal-views refactorings) the helper stops working.

I have created the following [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bekuhe) that demonstrates the problem.
Any idea what changed that causes the problem or better how it can be solved?

Comment: In this [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5595#issuecomment-57306695) a solution was proposed. Removing this line mysteriously solves the problem:

    Ember.Handlebars.helper(name, helper);